# Change node and attribute text in XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am stuck in parsing the below XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Provisioning xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Request>
    <Header>
      <Command>Create</Command>
      <EntityIdentifiers>
        <Identifier Type="CosName" Value="Super_Super"/>
      </EntityIdentifiers>
      <EntityName>COS</EntityName>
    </Header>
    <Data>
      <COS>
        <ServiceLevels>
          <ServiceLevel>
            <ServiceName>MMS</ServiceName>
            <ServiceLevelName>Super user</ServiceLevelName>
          </ServiceLevel>
          <ServiceLevel>
            <ServiceName>General</ServiceName>
            <ServiceLevelName>Super user</ServiceLevelName>
          </ServiceLevel>
          <ServiceLevel>
            <ServiceName>MMBOX</ServiceName>
            <ServiceLevelName>Super user</ServiceLevelName>
          </ServiceLevel>
        </ServiceLevels>
        <CosName>Super_Super</CosName>
      </COS>
    </Data>
  </Request>
</Provisioning>
```

I need to replace the "Identifier" tags "Type" and "Value" to other respective values. And also change all values of nodes under "ServiceLevel".

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "false"
xmlDoc.Load("C:\1.xml")
Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Identifier")
Set node = nodeXML.item(0)
MsgBox node.Text
```

Comment: VB Script is not VB .NET. Please adopt your tags.

Comment: want something like this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.heyscriptingguy.aspx ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft.XMLDOM` is outdated and shouldn't be used anymore. Use `Msxml2.DOMDocument` instead.

```vb
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
```

Select a single node with an [XPath expression](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) like this:

```vb
Set node = xml.SelectSingleNode("//node_name")
```

and several nodes with the same name like this:

```vb
Set nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//node_name")
```

Attributes of a node (`<node attribute="value">`) can be changed like this:

```vb
node.SetAttribute("attribute_name") = "new value"
```

and node text (`<node>text</node>`) like this:

```vb
node.Text = "new text"
```

Beware that the names of XML nodes and attributes are case-sensitive.