# How do I get a specific XML node in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML in powershell below:

```
[Xml]$MyXmlVariable = @"
<Mylist>
  <Item Number="1">
    <Name>"AMD Ryzen 5 3600x"</Name>
    <Type>"CPU"</Type>
    <Price>"$169.99"</Price>
    <Where>"Amazon"</Where>
    <Other>
      <ThreadCount>"12"</ThreadCount>
      <Cores>"6"</Cores>
    </Other>
  </Item>
</MyList>
"@
```

And it looks fne to me, but when I try to define it, I get the error

```
Cannot convert value "<Mylist>
  <Item Number="1">
    <Name>"AMD Ryzen 5 3600x"</Name>
    <Type>"CPU"</Type>
    <Price>".99"</Price>
    <Where>"Amazon"</Where>
    <Other>
      <ThreadCount>"12"</ThreadCount>
      <Cores>"6"</Cores>
    </Other>
  </Item>
</MyList>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The 'Mylist' start tag on line 1
position 2 does not match the end tag of 'MyList'. Line 12, position 3."
At line:1 char:1
+ [Xml]$MyXmlVariable = @"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

AFAIK there doesn't seem to be an error but Powershell says otherwise. Please Help

Comment: XMLs are case sensitive. `MyList` and `Mylist` are different so that is where the error comes from. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220463/change-node-and-attribute-text-in-xml-file/35227947#35227947

Comment: Thank you, when I changed `<Mylist>` to `<MyList>` it works :P. Sorry for the stupid question... One more thing, if I have multiple items and I want the item where the `Number` value is equal to 1 what would I do?

Comment: Use `?`/`Where-Object`, `$MyXmlVariable.MyList.Item | ? {$_.Number -eq 1}` you could do this with other values too, `$MyXmlVariable.MyList.Item | ? {$_.Type -eq "CPU"}`

Comment: Thank you, you solved my issues!

Comment: No problem, just one more thing, `$169.99` will not show because `$` expands to variables in powershell so use `$$169.99`, ```"`$169.99"``` or `'$169.99'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLs are case-sensitive so an XML like this:

```
<test></Test>
```

Will also not work having the error

```
Cannot convert value "<test></Test>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The 'test'
start tag on line 1 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'Test'. Line 1, position 9."
At line:1 char:1
+ [xml]"<test></Test>"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
```

In your XML, the starting and ending tags are different:

```
[Xml]@"
<Mylist>
<!--l is not capitalized-->
  <Item Number="1">
    <Name>"AMD Ryzen 5 3600x"</Name>
    <Type>"CPU"</Type>
    <Price>"$169.99"</Price>
    <Where>"Amazon"</Where>
    <Other>
      <ThreadCount>"12"</ThreadCount>
      <Cores>"6"</Cores>
    </Other>
  </Item>
</MyList>
<!--l is capitalized-->
"@
```

Which means that `<Mylist>` and `</MyList>` are two different nodes.

This is what is causing your error so try

```
[Xml]$MyXmlVariable = @"
<MyList>
  <Item Number="1">
    <Name>"AMD Ryzen 5 3600x"</Name>
    <Type>"CPU"</Type>
    <Price>"$169.99"</Price>
    <Where>"Amazon"</Where>
    <Other>
      <ThreadCount>"12"</ThreadCount>
      <Cores>"6"</Cores>
    </Other>
  </Item>
</MyList>
"@
```